# Consider the Dirichlet Series attached to the square of the Dedekind Eta function. Does this series admit an Euler product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

If so, is it the product of two Dirichlet L-Functions? Or could it be a linear combination of products of two Dirichlet L-Functions? My guess is that it is definitely not the product of two, and that it is either the latter or completely independent of Dirichlet L-Functions.

Comment: For $\eta(z)^2$ to have an Euler product, the coefficients of its Fourier series must be multiplicative. Is there any reason for this to be the case? Usually multiplicativity of the Fourier coefficients of a modular form $f$ is due to $f$ being an eigenfunction of every Hecke operator, but I see no reason for this to be the case for $\eta^2$.

Comment: Yes, as I have asked this question after calculating coefficients of this modular form, and they appear to be multiplicative for the ones ive tested.